# Using variables defined in an anonymous namespace in another namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces

I have this in a .cpp file:

```
namespace {
    std::string CListName;
}

namespace EXAMPLE_NS {
    CListName = "ListName";
    ...
```

But Eclipse highlights the assignment as a Syntax Error.  I take it you can't use an anonymous namespace from another namespace?

Comment: So I moved the assignment statements inside the constructor within the EXAMPLE_NS, seems to have sorted out the eclipse error and clicking the var name highlights the anonymous name also.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`CListName = "ListName";` is a statement (specifically, it's an assignment expression, which is an expression statement).

A statement cannot appear at namespace scope; you need to put the statement into a function.

Answer (score 3):

What you have there *is* a syntax error, but it's not a problem with the namespace.  What you have there is an assignment statement outside of any function or method. GCC tells me:

```
error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘=’ token
```

When trying to compile your snippet.  Clang has a better message:

```
error: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations
    CListName = "ListName";
    ^~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

It all means the same thing, though - you can't have statements outside of functions!

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can. Anonymous namespaces are the C++ way to remove the external linkage of the objects declared inside.

So I'd say it is a bug in the Eclipse syntax highlight.

Of course, you are doing the assignment into a function, not typed here for brevity, aren't you?

Comment: There is no bug here. You can't just assign things at namespace scope.